# How to fast processing one million strings to remove quotes and join them together

Tags: string, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to removing extra quotes from a large set of strings (a list of strings), so for each original string, it looks like,

```
"""str_value1"",""str_value2"",""str_value3"",1,""str_value4"""
```

I like to remove the start and end quotes and extra pairs of quotes on each string value, so the result will look like,

```
"str_value1","str_value2","str_value3",1,"str_value4"
```

and then join each string in the list by a new line.

I have tried the following code,

```
for line in str_lines[1:]:
        strip_start_end_quotes = line[1:-1]
        splited_line_rem_quotes = strip_start_end_quotes.replace('\"\"', '"')
        str_lines[str_lines.index(line)] = splited_line_rem_quotes

for_pandas_new_headers_str = '\n'.join(splited_lines)
```

but it is really slow (running for ages) if the list contains over 1 million string lines. So what is the best way to do that in terms of time efficiency?

I also tried to multiprocessing this task by

```
def preprocess_data_str_line(data_str_lines):
"""

:param data_str_lines:
:return:
"""
    for line in data_str_lines:
        strip_start_end_quotes = line[1:-1]
        splited_line_rem_quotes = strip_start_end_quotes.replace('\"\"', '"')
        data_str_lines[data_str_lines.index(line)] = splited_line_rem_quotes

    return data_str_lines


def multi_process_prepcocess_data_str(data_str_lines):
    """

    :param data_str_lines:
    :return:
    """
    # if cpu load < 25% and 4GB of ram free use 3 cores
    # if cpu load < 70% and 4GB of ram free use 2 cores
    cores_to_use = how_many_core()

    data_str_blocks = slice_list(data_str_lines, cores_to_use)

    for block in data_str_blocks:
        # spawn processes for each data string block assigned to every cpu core
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=preprocess_data_str_line, args=(block,))
        p.start()
```

but I don't know how to concatenate the results back into the list so that I can join the strings in the list by new lines.

So, ideally, I am thinking about using multiprocessing + a fast function to preprocessing each line to speed up the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine a large amount of processing time is spent on the `data_str_lines.index(line)` - to find the line for the nth element, it has to look through N-1 elements first to locate the index of your original line (so instead of looping 1 million times, you're looping ~**500 billion** times). Instead - keep track of your current index and update your list as you go, eg:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(data_str_lines):
    # Do whatever you need to do with `line`... to create a `new_line`
    # ...
    # Update line to be the new line
    data_str_lines[idx] = new_line

for_pandas = '\n'.join(data_str_lines)
```

Comment: what if I just want to iterate a sub list of `data_str_lines`, e.g. `data_str_lines[1:]`, I found the `idx` is 0 for the 1st string in the sublist instead of 1in the original list; so have to `idx+1`; is there a straight way get its original index.

Comment: @daiyue use `enumerate(data_str_lines[1:], start=1)`

Comment: The slice would create a copy though, so if you really want to avoid memory overhead, you could use: `enumerate(itertools.islice(data_str_lines, 1, None), start=1)`

Comment: any idea on how to multiprocess the task, and concatenate the results from each process?

Comment: yeah... but that's a different question all together... and for the setup costs of getting it working, you won't actually get a performance boost - at best, it just won't be too much slower :)